# why the map function removes column from the dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a csv file

```
datetime,name
20-10-2019 14:55,a
19-10-2019 14:55,b
```

when i apply map method second column gone

```
df.info()
#df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(str) # if your object is datatime
df1 = df['datetime'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
df1.to_frame()
```

My Out

```
datetime
0   2019-10-20
1   2019-10-19
```

My expected out include the column name 'name' also. Is there any `regex` to do this operation

Comment: @orlp already answered, but additionally you shouldn't operate on `datetime` as on string but use `to_datetime` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that map removed a column or that a column has been removed at all. You simply selected a single column from your dataframe so that is what you end up getting.

Try

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].map(...)
```

to update the datetime column in your original dataframe instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('time.csv')
#df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
#df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].astype(str)
df1 = df['datetime'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
df1.to_frame()
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])

import re

def split_it(year):
    return re.findall('(\d\d\d\d)', year)

df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(split_it)
```